# How to specify javax.persistence.lock.scope in spring data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring boot along with spring data for data communication with the database.

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("select s from Seat s where s.id=:id")
Seat findById(@Param("id")Integer id);
```

I have specified the lock but I also want to specify other parameters like lock scope, lock timeout. I have searched but not able to find.
One solution that I found over the internet is to use

```
 @QueryHints(value={@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.scope",   value   ="EXTENDED" )})
```

But the above solution is not working and it can be validated from the logs below.

Hibernate: select seat0_.id as id1_1_, seat0_.aisle_seat as aisle_se2_1_, seat0_.booking_status as booking_3_1_, seat0_.row_name as row_name4_1_, seat0_.screen_id as screen_i6_1_, seat0_.seat_number as seat_num5_1_ from seat seat0_ where seat0_.id=? for update

Hibernate: select screen0_.id as id1_0_0_, screen0_.name as name2_0_0_ from screen screen0_ where screen0_.id=?

there is not lock statement (for update for the screen).

How to add such attribute in spring data?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `javax.persistence.lock.scope`, is not yet supported in Hibernate

I wrote about it here [Locking entity foreign key in JPA](https://medium.com/@IEnoobong/locking-entity-foreign-key-in-jpa-dbda9c747d07)

> The javax.persistence.lock.scope is not yet supported as specified by the JPA standard.

From [Hibernate Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-jpa-query-hints)

[Related Ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9636)

Comment: is it supported now?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be correct behavior as  `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` is the equivalent of `"SELECT FOR UPDATE"`.

Using `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)` can be seen in `lock in share mode` logs:

```
Hibernate: select seat0_.id as id1_0_, seat0_.seat_no as seat_no2_0_ from seat seat0_ where seat0_.id=? lock in share mode
```